# jRange range picker set value problems

Tags: jquery, html, css

Just wondering how to set the value on the jRange range picker.

Following the documentation it says to do the code below, although the 2 dots seemed to be pinned in random spots.

```
$('.range-slider').jRange({
    from: 0,
    to: 36,
    step: 0.25,
    scale: [0, 6, 12, 6, 12, 6, 0],
    format: '%s',
    width: '100%',
    showLabels: true,
    isRange: true
});
$('.range-slider').jRange('setValue', '20,26');
```

Comment: All you need is a function to transfer position and which index you are referring to, just refer to my answer (just wanted to make sure you saw the update).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `scale` settings array is not correct, it should be `[0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36]` instead of `[0, 6, 12, 6, 12, 6, 0]`

```js
$('.range-slider').jRange({
  from: 0,
  to: 36,
  step: 0.25,
  scale: [0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36],
  format: '%s',
  width: '100%',
  showLabels: true,
  isRange: true
});
$('.range-slider').jRange('setValue', '20,26');
```

```html
<link href="http://nitinhayaran.github.io/jRange/jquery.range.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://nitinhayaran.github.io/jRange/jquery.range.js"></script>
<div class="demo-output">
  <input class="range-slider" type="hidden" value="0.0" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('.range-slider').jRange('updateRange', '0,36','20,26');`

> sets the current value of the slider without changing its range, if you want to update the range as well use updateRange instead.
>
> Use 'updateRange' to change (min, max) value and interval after
> initialized.

From http://nitinhayaran.github.io/jRange/demo/ near the bottom!

Comment: I don't want to change the range I just want to set where the 2 dots are going to be positioned when the slider is loaded. Is it what you meant ?

Comment: That's what the second pair of numbers is for `'0,36','20,26'`. I don't think you can only set the range after initialization thought. Can you switch the plugin for something with more options and easier? : https://refreshless.com/nouislider/examples/

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple repeating indexes scalars.  And the range is simply counting 1 to 36, ignoring whatever scales you have.  **That is only for display**.

However, you can write a function to get around this.

See:

```js
function getPos(i,lc) {
 return i + 12 * lc;
}

$('.range-slider').jRange({
    from: 0,
    to: 36,
    step: 0.25,
    scale: [0, 6, 12, 6, 12, 6, 0],
    format: '%s',
    width: '100%',
    showLabels: true,
    isRange: true
});
$('.range-slider').jRange('setValue', getPos(6,1) + "," + getPos(6,2));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://neil.computer/stack/jquery.range.css">
<script src="http://neil.computer/stack/jquery.range-min.js"></script>
<div class="range-slider"></div>
```